# Ubuntu hanging due to some strange './b 22 300' commands

Tags: server

I am having a strange issue with my Ubuntu setup (hosted in AWS EC2). Many a times, my server starts choking and after some time, just stops responding.

Today, I was logged in the server, and the HTOP command showed the following output:
[image: HTOP]

As shown in the picture, there were a lot of './b 22 300' commands, which were constantly closing/spawning. After some time, the server displayed the same issues as always: stopped responding.

Normally the output of HTOP is this:
[image: Normal Output]

Can anyone help me with what exactly are these ./b commands?

Comment: you also have ./a in there. could you please do a 'sudo lsof -u admin' and add this to your question.

Comment: Hi s1mmel. The server hanged almost immediately after I took the screenshot. I can post the output of isof, but the output will be current and currently HTOP does not show any ./a or ./b commands. Should I do it anyway?

Comment: Did you try to find those files? To me this looks like a "hack" somehow.

Comment: I tried, but couldn't find any.

Comment: So if you don't know those files and didn't start them at all and they don't belong to any of the software you run on your server, I guess your server might be compromised (hacked).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. Posting this here for anybody who faces this issue.

This issue arose due to VestaCP. I installed it briefly and then uninstalled it, but somehow, the user 'admin' which was created by it was not removed, neither the 'admin' user directory, nor the cron jobs created by VestaCP.

Due to this, hackers/bots somehow started brute force attacks on the vestacp ip (along with ssh, which was saved by fail2ban). These connection requests spawned these ./b commands and brought down the server.

The solution to this is:

1. Remove the admin user created by the following commands: `killall -u admin -m .` & `userdel admin`.
2. After this, delete the home directory of the admin user (i.e. `\home\admin`) and also delete the cron file for the user: `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/admin`.